# null is not an object (evaluating i.category._id)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I'm still learning react-native and trying to retrieve data from API but I got this error:
[image: error msg]

the

> initialState is set to ([])

```
   // Product container
  const changeCtg = (ctg) => {
    {
      ctg === "all"
        ? [setProductsCtg(initialState), setActive(true)]
        : [
            setProductsCtg(
              products.filter((i) => i.category._id === ctg),
              setActive(true)
            ),
          ];
    }
  };
```

Comment: What's `products`? Apparently one of elements of that array is either `null`, or its `category` prop is equal to null.

Comment: Please add more code of your component. Why are you setting state within an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this error because category is null or undefined.
you can use [optional chaining (?)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) if your project support it.

products.filter((i) => i.category?._id === ctg)

or

products.filter((i) => i.category && i.category._id === ctg)